# webpack-dev-server not serving bundle from config location with react-router param route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

Using react-router my routes match and my app bundle SearchUXBundle.js correctly loads from first level routes - but second level routes /tracker/:id incorrectly are trying to load my app bundle from localhost/tracker/dist/SearchUXBundle.js instead of localhost/dist/SearchUXBundle.js.  im assuming this is some kind of config wrinkle in webpack 'output' relating to relative paths that im missing...

webpack.config,js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
        inline:false,
        port: 8001,
        historyApiFallback: true 
  },
  entry: {
    app: ['./src/root.js']
  },

  output: {
          path: "/dist",
          publicPath: '/',
          filename: '/dist/SearchUXBundle.js'
    },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          retainLines: true,
          cacheDirectory: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /.css$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css']     
      },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|woff)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192' },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
      alias: {
          __CONFIG__: path.join(__dirname, 'config', process.env.REACT_ENV)
      }
  }
};
```

app.js

```
...
const store = createStore(rootReducer, enhancer);
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store, {
  selectLocationState: createSelectLocationState()
});

render(
  <Provider store={store} >
     <Router history={history}> 
        <Route path="/" component={SearchUXContainer} />
        <Route path="tracker/:id" component={EmailTrackerContainer}/>
        <Route path="thisWorks" component={SearchUXContainer}/>
     </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Can you include your `index.html`. My first guess would be that the `SearchUXBundle.js` in your `index.html` is relative when it should be absolute.

Comment: bingo! so i had improperly linked "dist/SearchBundle.js" - the other problem i found was that i had improperly nested my routes under   <Route path="/"...>. If you would like to roll this into an answer i will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that the linked bundle in your `index.html` file is absolute. If it is relative, then the location will vary based on the URL and any nested routes will point to a non-existent location.

```
<!-- bad -->
<script src="dist/SearchUXBundle.js"></script>

<!-- good -->
<script src="/dist/SearchUXBundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: great answer!
Note for those using HtmlWebPackPlugin:
make sure the config object specifies {files.js:['/bundle.js']}